# WordPress MultiSite Won't Work on Google AppEngine

Tags: multisite, google

I'm receiving this error when trying to access network dashboard on app engine:

```
Warning: require(C:\Users\Jon\Documents\GitHub\kapx-wordpress\wp-admin\network): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 106
```

I've added these handlers to no avail.  Anybody else have any luck?

```
- url: /wp-admin/network/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/network/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/network/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/network/index.php
  secure: always
```

Comment: Questions that are too localized (such as syntax errors, code with restricted access, hacked sites, hosting or support issues) are not in scope here on WP Dev.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are doing and how, since it's (relatively) not very common platform? Your error message seems to indicate local developments setup, what is it precisely?

Comment: I am leaving this open as we can file it under "server administration".

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is a third party host and dealing with them is really off topic here. That error is a simple permission and/or file error and has nothing to do with WordPress itself.

You're beter off asking at Google http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ or trying https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-app-engine/